# .SystemUpdate() / .Update() on ItemUpdating

Tags: update

I'm updating an item and getting the version of this item to input its value in another list.

The big problem is that I need to verify if a field on the afterproperties is diferent of the new value in the ItemUpdated.

- Simple Question 1:
  How can I verify (in ItemUpdated) the original value of a field(column) ?
- Simple Question 2:
  How can I do an UPDATE on the ItemUpdating without receive conflict message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In ItemUpdated you can get previous field values only from item's
   version history
2. In the ItemUpdating your can set up
   `AfterProperties["YourFieldInternalName"]` to set new filed values to
   current list item